# How to access HttpServletRequest from Spring for Graphql WebGraphQlInterceptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql-java, spring-graphql

I am working on moving to Spring for GraphQL from kickstarter. And we used a custom Context in kickstart implementing `GraphQLKickstartContext`. However, this is not supported in Spring for GraphQl and we want to add some headers, parameters and attributes from `HttpServletRequest` to the `GraphQLContext`. Appreciate your help.

Trial: In the `WebGraphQlInterceptor`, you can access the Headers, but not the parameters nor the attributes (accessing debug parameter, security.web.username attribute etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Spring for GraphQL won't give you access to the actual HTTP request implementation, as this `WebGraphQlInterceptor` contract is meant to be used by Servlet and non-Servlet environments.

Looking at `WebGraphQlRequest`, this should contain everything you need already:

- HTTP headers
- URI
- cookies
- request attributes